# Find columns which come in pair with multiple/various other-column values

Tags: mysql

I have a points table, where important columns are:

```
id         userid        orderid
1          10            150
2          10            150
3          15            151
4          12            152
5          11            152
```

I need to find all `orderid` which have multiple/various `userid`. The result would be:

```
id         userid        orderid
4          12            152
5          11            152
```

I can do it in PHP, but I hope someone have time to help me with mysql query. What I have tried so far is probably irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COUNT(DISTINCT)` and `HAVING` to find orderid with multiple various userid.

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3cd87/3/0)**

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tab t
JOIN (SELECT orderid, COUNT(DISTINCT userid) 
      FROM tab
      GROUP BY orderId
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT userid) > 1) AS sub
  ON t.orderid = sub.orderid
ORDER BY t.id
```

Comment: Just tested it and it works as expected. Thank you for your time!

Comment: I know it can do it, but I can't :) Unfortunately, it is kind of doom for web developers, one knows all and nothing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get just the rows that have same `orderid` but **different** `userid`, use this:

```
SELECT P1.* FROM points P1 
INNER JOIN points P2 
    ON P1.orderid = P2.orderid and P1.id != P2.id and P1.userid != p2.userid;
```

Note that this first *select* returns what you expect in your question:

```
+----+--------+---------+
| id | userid | orderid |
+----+--------+---------+
|  4 |     12 |     152 |
|  5 |     11 |     152 |
+----+--------+---------+
```

---

Now, if you want to return ANY `orderid` that is the same, regardless of `userid`, use this:

```
SELECT P1.* FROM points P1 
INNER JOIN points P2 
    ON P1.orderid = P2.orderid and P1.id != P2.id;
```

In this case, it won't exclude the result with same id, returning

```
+----+--------+---------+
| id | userid | orderid |
+----+--------+---------+
|  1 |     10 |     150 |
|  2 |     10 |     150 |
|  4 |     12 |     152 |
|  5 |     11 |     152 |
+----+--------+---------+
```

Comment: What does `; --` means in condition?

Comment: I think you understood wrong. `;` just ends the code. `--` means that everything in front of it is a comment, so `and P1.userid != p2.userid;` won't be executed. If you run the code without `; --`, only different userid with same orderid will return. I'll edit my answer to make it clear.

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense now.